# Как мне сделать что-бы каждый вывод был элементом

Tags: python

Мне нужно что бы каждый новый вывод добавлялся как элемент в список

```
import requests as req
a = -1
slave = []
while a < 2:
    a +=1
    resp = req.get('https://example.com')
    slave.append(resp.text)
```

но когда я вывожу этот код выводиться всё как 1 элемент

Как мне сделать что-бы каждый вывод был элементом

Comment: Как вы выводите?

Comment: `print(slave)` `print(slave[0])`

Comment: print(slave) у вас должен выводить весь список. Попробуйте вывести на каждой итерации список и посмотрите, как он меняется.

Comment: Происходить что то вроде
`[text]`
`[texttext]`
`[textextext]`
А мне нужно что бы в итоге список выглядел так:
`[text][text][text]`

Comment: Когда вы делаете slave.append(resp.text), вы добавляете элемент в список. У вас должно получаться ['text', 'text', 'text']. https://ideone.com/0ufUc4 Я не знаю, что вы такое делаете, что у вас получается [textextext].

Comment: @krime, чтобы получить вывод как у вас в примере, то в список надо добавить ещё несколько списков. Например: `[[text],[text],[text]]`

Comment: Да @КириллМалышев ваш код у меня тоже работает , но у вас нет запроса к сайту, а когда я пытаюсь получить запрос и добавить его в список он добавляет только 1

Comment: Попробуйте добавлять в `slave не text, а resp.status_code`

Comment: Вывод лишь трижды код 200 но они тоже идут как 1 элемент